# Update Database in C# after using JsonPatchDocument.ApplyTo

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

So here is my problem. I have an httpPatch endpoint where I have to do an update.

Here is the code

```
        [HttpPatch, Route("api/serversTarget/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult updateEntity(int id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<ServerTarget> patchEntity)
        {
            var entity = db.getAllServers().FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id);

            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            patchEntity.ApplyTo(entity);

            //UPDATE in Oracle Database
            db.updateServerInDatabase(entity);
            return Ok(entity);
        }
```

I get all the db entries when the program starts and put them into a list (getAllServers()). My question is how do I know what changes have been made by patchEntity.ApplyTo() so I can update the database accordingly.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework (Core)? If yes, then shouldn’t this already work as EF tracks all changes made to an entity?

Comment: No i am not using Core. ASP .NET 4 (I think)

Comment: i don't understand your requirement here, why do want to know what changes was made to entity, as you are going to call update on whole entity.

Comment: ok so I might have not gotten my point across. I want to only update only the things about the entity that have changed and not the whole entity.